# Ajax xml source parsing depend on click action with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parsing

I have an AJAX xml parsing:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: "data/content_data.xml",
    dataType:"xml",
    success: function(xml) {
```

Is there any option to change source after click at some button element? For example, I click at button_01 and script load source from `url: "data/content_data_01.xml"`, click at button_02 load source from `url: "data/content_data_02.xml"`.

Comment: Do you mean Java or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.  There are a number of ways to do this.  Basically you just use a string variable for your url value instead of a literal string.  You could perhaps define an object that you would use to lookup the values liek this

```
var buttonIDtoURL = {
    "button_01": "data/content_data_01.xml",
    "button_02": "data/content_data_02.xml"
}

$(".button_class").click(function() {
    var urlToUse = buttonIDtoURL[$(this).id];
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: urlToUse,
        dataType:"xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            // your success handler here
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: how to reset this after click other button, it will change automaticly?

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski Yes it would look at the id of your of the clicked button (in this case button_01 or button_02) and look up the URL value from the buttonIDtoURL object literal that was defined.

Comment: and as button id in action .click i need to use button_01 and button_02?

Comment: I have edited my answer to give a better idea as to how you might call the ajax function from within a click handler. In this case, you would need to apply some class to your buttons in order to select them.  You then get the URL to use based on the id of the clicked button on the first line fo the click handler function.

Answer (score 0):

Set up some buttons:

```
<input type="button" id="B01" value="Get nr. one" />
<input type="button" id="B02" value="Get nr. two"/>
```

and do some jQuery stuff:

```
$('button').on('click', function() { //attach click handler
    doAjax(this.id.replace('B','')).done(function(xml) { // remove B and do ajax
        //do something with xml in the deferred callback
    });
});

function doAjax(url_id) { //url_id value will be 01 or 02 and ....
    return $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "data/content_data_"+url_id+".xml", //is inserted here in the url
        dataType:"xml"
    });
}
```